# No way to adjust baud rate in connect() with Dronekit 2 and 3DR Radios and Pixhawk?

Tags: dronekit-python

I am unable to connect to my Pixhawk drone with 3DR radios and Dronekit 2 and Python code.

I am able to connect with a USB cable attached to Pixhawk.

I suspect the problem is the baud rate with the radios are too high.

There seems to be no way to change the baud rate with the radios in the connect command.

Please advise.

Windows 8.1

Thank you!

Comment: `vehicle = connect(args.connect, baud=57600)` does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Found out from another website that there was a bug in the releases prior to Dronkit 2.0.0.rc9.  They forgot to put in any way to adjust baud rate!  Latest release Dronekit 2.0.0.rc10 has the fix.